# When to use $em->getConnection()->close();, should I use it after every query

Tags: java, php, hibernate, doctrine-orm

I am new to doctrine2(PHP) which is inspired from hibernate(java). I have searched at many places by didn't get appropriate answer.

what is the use of following code of line, what will happen if I do not use it?

```
        $em->getConnection()->close();
```

For example If I have made following method in my class :

```
public static function deleteWish( $about_ilook_user_id, $link_ilook_user_id, $flush_automatic = TRUE )
{
    $em = \Zend_Registry::get('em');
    $new_link_wishes_objs = $em->getRepository( '\Entities\new_link_wishes' )->findBy( array( 'ilookUser' => $about_ilook_user_id, 'link_ilook_user_id' => $link_ilook_user_id ) );
    foreach ( $new_link_wishes_objs as $new_link_wishes_obj )
    {   
        $em -> remove($new_link_wishes_obj);
    }

    $em -> flush();
    $em->getConnection()->close();
}
```

Should I call getConnection()->close(); on $em(entity manager).

Comment: There is no need to explicitly call it for web applications.  DB connections will automatically be closed at the end of the request.

Comment: Ok nice. If not to use in web applications then we do we use this?

Comment: Only for very long running processes where you don't want to tie up the connection.  For all practical purposes, you never need to use it.